# How to implement tab bar with swipe like facebook menu(Message,notification,friend request) in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android same as facebook.It contains tab bar with swipe to navigate to other page. Default it will display profile page. When user click on tab bar menu it will allow user to swipe the page to view other fragments. When user click on back button it will shows the default profile page as like in facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create Android Tabbed style with Page Swipe View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265796/how-to-create-android-tabbed-style-with-page-swipe-view)

Comment: I am looking what you have mentioned. i already implemented that.

Comment: So you have to explain more by providing some piece of code, where you stuck