# Tab Layout with Sliding Views

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs, view, sliding

I want to create an app that uses a tab layout with sliding views (something like this):

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the issue: 
I searched all over the web for a guide that could explain how to do this kind of thing but all I tried didn't work for me. I read somewhere that tabs layout is deprecated with Lollipop, so I tried to find an alternative way to do what I wanted to do, but nothing. Every tab layout app I try to create ends up with a crash while testing and I think it's due to something about the `ActionBar`, always because of the `ActionBar` Tabs are deprecated in Lollipop. I'm not going to post any code because I created so many projects that I lost their count, and also because they are quite the same.
So, anyone could please link me a guide or explain a working method that allows to do what I explained?

All I can say is that the app has to be used on Lollipop, so I'd like to know the compile settings to put in the gradle files.
Another important thing is that i use Android Studio, even if most of the tutorials i find on web are about Eclipse.

I hope to have explained in detail my problem and what i want to do and i thank you all in advance.

Comment: look at https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip with Toolbar and ViewPager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create Android Tabbed style with Page Swipe View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265796/how-to-create-android-tabbed-style-with-page-swipe-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailled description of how to use the SlidingTabLayout like Google uses it in the Store:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout

Like Hugo already mentioned: it works with viewpager

Comment: I'm looking at the link you gave me and i cannot understand one thing.
When i have to work with imports like `Fragments`, which one have i to use between `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.Fragment`? I often had this problem due to deprecated types/methods. Thanks!

Comment: There is a question about fragments in the support library vs the app Fragments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager